# Can't see any image preview in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor, blend-modes

I've added two strips of images after the video strip and converted their blend mode to Alpha Over. But there is still no preview image in VSE when pressing "Play". What should I do?
Filetype of images is PNG, version of Blender is 2.73, graphic card is gtx860, after rendering the part of video with images I see black screen.

Comment: Your trying to turn them into a video? you need a video format like AVI

Comment: @ARaddish No need to have a video file, the VSE works fine with image sequences.

Comment: @ARadish For some reasons I think it doesn't matter, what's the output format. It is just simple insert of image to show in video...

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a few screen shots of what you have in your time line?

Comment: Check your PNG's alpha and the strip's opacity (and the eye icon) in N panel

Comment: @Bithur Hm, these PNG files were created by pressing Win+PrtSc and they were not processed correctly by Blender for unknown reasons. Recreating a PNG file by another standalone application solved my strange problem.

Answer (score 1):

**This was not a Blender issue.**

My PNG files were created by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and they were not processed correctly by Blender for unknown reasons. Recreating the PNG file in another application solved my strange problem.